# Load json data from backend into typescript/angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to load a json data from backend service to my angular app. I want to load/push data into an array. Below is what my data from backend looks like

```
{   "Record":[
  {
     "Name":"John",
     "Place":"Seattle"
  },
  {
     "Name":"AS2",
     "Place":"DC"
  }]}
```

Here is my array model class in typescript

```
export class EventMaster {
  public name: string;
  public cityName: string;
  constructor (name: string, cityName: string){
    this.cityName = cityName;
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

Here is my typescript code which I am using to fetch data from back-end and load into array

```
  private eventMaster: EventMaster[] = [
   new EventMaster('Loan', 'Approved' )
  ];

  onFetchData(form: HTMLFormElement){
    console.log(form);
    console.log(form.value);
    this.nameCity = new NameCity(form.value.name, form.value.city);

    this.fetchDataService.fetchData(this.nameCity).subscribe(
      (data: EventMaster[]) => {
        console.log(data);
        this.eventMaster.push(...data);
        console.log(this.eventMaster.length);
      }
        );

  }
```

Here is my http get call

```
 fetchData(nameCity: NameCity) {

  return this.http.get<EventMaster[]>(this.baseURL);

  }
```

When I try to check the length of array it always shows as 1 and not 2. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try this `this.eventMaster = [...this.eventMaster, ...data];` instead of push.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to map the result of your get API call

```
fetchData(nameCity: NameCity) {
    return this.http.get(this.baseURL).map((res: any) => res.Record.map(r=>new EventMaster(r.Name, r.Place));
}
```

Comment: Based on my understanding , if I am using HTTPClient then angular does extract the body for me. So I need not to use "map". Is that incorrect ?

Comment: You don't need to use map if the structure of your json data corresponds to the structure of the models declared in angular. In your example, actualy data is wrapped in a `Record` property, and has `Name` and `Place` properties instead of `name` and `cityName` in your model. You can just do a `console.log(data)` in your question's code to check that it's going to be empty

Answer (score 0):

How is onFetchData executed? It might be running only once. Also place console.log(this.eventMaster.length); outside of this function and try

Comment: The backend call was completed and I could see the response in console when I log data. It's just not getting loaded into array